# Viewing laser scan data coming from Raspberry pi using Laptop

Tags: ros, ros2, rviz, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04 with ros2 humble. My laptop is running Ubuntu 20.04 with ros1 noetic. I have connected a Slamtec RPLIDAR A3 with my Raspberry Pi and want to view its laser scan in RViz. I have added their [ros2 package](https://github.com/Slamtec/sllidar_ros2/tree/main) for my Raspberry Pi board. the launch file in the package opens the rviz2 in the Raspberry Pi, but there is no display connected to my Raspberry Pi.

Can I view the laser scan readings from my raspberry pi using my laptops Rviz?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to set it up after setting x11 server and x11 forwarding. Thank you for all of your support as well.

Comment: What is an x11 server? How did you set it up? What did you have to forward? As written, this gives future visitors from *hints* as to what they need to do, but not any details. Please edit this answer to help other people that have your same problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no." ROS1 and ROS2 use different middleware for message transport. You can run the `ros1_bridge` https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge on the Raspberry Pi to convert the ROS2 messages to ROS1 messages.

Alternatively, you can grab a desktop version of a ROS2 docker container and run it on your laptop using Rocker https://github.com/osrf/rocker. Then you would have a full RViz2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: I was able to set it up after setting x11 server and x11 forwarding. Thank you for your support as well.

Comment: Why don't you write up your solution and post it here and then accept it as an answer? That way other people with the same question can try your solution.